# Javascript AudioContext check not working in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, audiocontext

I have this `JS` code where I am checking if `AudioContext` is defined then set it otherwise return `undefined`:

```
function audioContextCheck() {
    if (typeof AudioContext !== "undefined") {
        return new AudioContext();
    } else if (typeof webkitAudioContext !== "undefined") {
        return new webkitAudioContext();
    } else if (typeof mozAudioContext !== "undefined") {
        return new mozAudioContext();
    } else {

       // return undefined
       return "undefined"

    }
}

var audioContext = audioContextCheck();
console.log(audioContext)

function audioRecording( e ) {

         try{
            console.log('audioContext is '+ audioContext)
            if (audioContext != "undefined") {
                audioContext.resume().then(() => {
                console.log('Resumed audioContext on end-recording');
                e.classList.remove('recording');
                recording = false;

            });
            }
            else {
                console.log('IE audioContext not supported')
                e.classList.remove('recording');
                recording = false;
                socketio.emit('end-recording');
            }
        }
        catch(error){
            console.log(error)
            console.log('Resumed audioContext on end-recording');
            e.classList.remove('recording');
            recording = false;

        }

    } 
}
```

Now this `JS` file is loaded from a `html` page. But in `Internet Explorer 11` whenever I load this page I can see `syntax error` at line `audioContext.resume().then(() => {`. I know IE does not support `AudioContext` and that's why I am using `audioContextCheck()` where I return `undefined` if `AudioContext` is not supported and then in `audioRecording()` I check if varaible `audioContext` is not equal to `undefined` then only execute the code under it. So for `IE` it should not execute that code but it still throws syntax error at the line.

Also I have `console.log()` statement in my code but I do not see anything coming on the console in `IE 11`(in dev tools).

What is the mistake I am doing here and what would be a more elegant way to make sure IE does not go to the error throwing line and thus does not throw error?

Comment: `() => {` is ES2015 syntax, that Internet Exploder does not understand - therefore, your javascript can not be *parsed* in Internet Exploder - therefore *none of it can be executed* - if you need to use *modern* javascript and still support internet exploder, look into transpilers (such as babeljs) TL;DR - since the code is not *parsable* by IE, none of it runs - nothing at all to do with Internet Exploders lack of AudioContext

Comment: @JaromandaX I am not too familiar with javascript(very very basic understanding) but since I am doing check for `audioContext` value before that line so shouldn't that line be not executed at all as I am assuming in IE my `audioContext` value should be equal to `undefined`.

Comment: Code needs to parse, that is, be syntactically correct. IE doesn't understand `=>` which means the whole "block" of javascript (script tag?) is discarded. Think of it as "compiling" - you can't execute a program that doesn't "compile"

Comment: @JaromandaX ok. So how can I modify my code so that it works in IE as well as other browsers. I am using `audioContext.resume().then(() => {` because chrome browser needs to resume audioContext as it by default pauses the audioContext until a user action happens

Comment: don't use ES2015 syntax at all ... so `.then(function() {....})` instead of `.then(() => {....})` - but also read about the difference between *regular* functions and [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) - the code you've shown seems to be unaffected by using regular instead of arrow -when you wrote this code, why did you decide to use an arrow function there?

Comment: just a follow up, imagine you had python code (I see you are active in Python tag) `if False: blah blah blah` - exactly that, as written - now, False is never True, but you still get a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` error, and the code doesn't run :p

Comment: @JaromandaX I used the arrow function as I saw example of audioContext.resume using it so I though that was the way to use it(like I said my lack of knowledge in javascript :p). Now I got it(with python example)!

Comment: that's the problem with examples on the internet these days - they all assume you either don't want to support IE, or know how to support IE if you have to :p